# pgAdmin 4 version 3.0 Query tool Initializing error on opening any query editor in browser

Tags: pgadmin-4

When clicking on a table and then selecting 'Query tool' results in an error.
I also couldn't find the log folder of pgAdmin.

[image: Query Tool Initialize Error]

It doesn't matter where I open the editor it always shows this editor.

I have re-installed multiple times, version: 10.4 and 9.6.9 search on stackoverflow for a lot of different solutions like resetting the layout or changing the local ip from 127.0.0.1 to localhost.

My teacher also never saw this before, so he couldn't help me either.

If anyone has had this problem before I would really know what the solution is. Apart from re-installing windows.

EDIT:

I have re-installed windows... And stept away from pgAdmin now. I use another tool  (HeidiSQL).

Comment: PGadmin is browser based for the first time in the latest version 3.0, so from that respect its new to everyone. For myself, in Chrome, I have to allow pop-ups for the query tool to run. You might need to do something similar

Comment: BTW the log for me is at  C:\Users\Myname\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin\pgadmin4.log but it probably won't help you with connection issues, I think it's more like sql errors

Comment: This is a bug and already reported https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/3433

Answer (score 2):

This problem has plagued me for months. Finally, I stumbled across a fix that worked for me. I hope it helps you.

In the Internet Explorer browser that is running `pgAdmin4` I turned off `SmartScreen Filter` under *Settings -> Safety*, and this instantly fixed the problem.